# VS2010 Web Deployment Package - Prevent App_Data from Being Deleted

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to deploy an update to a website using the Web Deployment capability of VS2010, generally following this guidance:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx

The production website uses certain data files in `App_Data` that are generated and deposited there by a separate service.

When I do a test deployment of my update:

```
MyDeploymentPackage.cmd /T
```

I get a message that everything in `App_Data` will be **deleted**.  If I uncheck the checkbox "Exclude files from the App_Data folder", I instead am informed that the files will be updated with an old copy of the files from the QA environment (if said files are included in the project), or that the specific files will be deleted (if the QA copy is not included in the project).

Is it possible to use a Web Deployment Package such that it just leaves `App_Data` alone?